# Solution to error in executing trigger on a relation

Tags: sql, oracle

I just created a trigger on employee table as after updating new value of salary must be large or similar to old salary.

[showing error in running trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYLut.png)
showing the code of the trigger

```
  create trigger fix_salary
  after update on employee
  for each row
  when(old.salary>new.salary)
  begin
  update employee 
  set salary=:old.salary;
  end;
  /
```

after that i added this to a text file and saved it with .plsql extension.
then i added to cmd as:-
  @"path of the flie";

and when i put a update command as:-

```
update employee set salary=1000 where eid=1;
```

after that this error is displayed:

```
update employee set salary=500 where eid=1
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.EMPLOYEE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.FIX_SALARY", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.FIX_SALARY'
```

Comment: This Oracle, not MySQL. Tag altered.

Comment: It looks like you are modifying the same table. Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert

Comment: Oracle has the same issue, check this way to achieve the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492015/oracle-trigger-to-update-a-the-same-table

Comment: Oracle recommends ___not___ creating user objects, such as tables or triggers, in the SYSTEM schema.

Comment: According to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users): _Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer_ I Googled for the terms ___oracle trigger table is mutating___ and got almost 50,000 results, including [Get rid of mutating table trigger errors with the compound trigger](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html)

Comment: @nageshwar Please don't put pictures here. Instead paste as code.

Comment: Share the code of the trigger